# how can i make fabric.js save the state/ position of each object in canvas and restore back for future editing?

Tags: save, html5-canvas, fabricjs, restore

What format can allow me to save my drawing on canvas in file (not in the image file), and allow me to restore back for future editing, means the file can remember all the position of the object add into canvas and allow me to edit it in the future?
[MY WORK](http://www.abluish.com/)

this is my work for now, just need a save button...

Comment: Please read the FabricjJS documentation: [`toJSON`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29034251/how-do-i-bind-onclick-event-to-piechart-segment/29040839#29040839)?

Answer (score 4):

You can save it as JSON & restore back for future editing.

**Sample Code:**

```
var canvas = json = '';
json = canvas.toJSON();
canvas.loadFromJSON(json, CallBack, function(o, object) {
    canvas.setActiveObject(object);
});

function CallBack() {
    canvas.renderAll();
    canvas.calcOffset();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for ur code, i figure out another solution already^^