# Smooth click event animation on canvas

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I am trying to implement an animation in canvas, something like a fan. When you click on a path, this should go almost 70% of screen, second and third path should go 15% of width.

Here is my code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


var el1 = {
    lineWidth: 1,
    fill: "blue",
    points: []
};
var el2 = {
    lineWidth:1,
  fill: 'red',
  points: []
}
var el3 = {
    lineWidth:1,
  fill:'green',
  points:[]
}
var paths = [];
paths.push(el1);
paths.push(el2);
paths.push(el3);


newPoint(50, 50, el1);
newPoint(100, 20, el1);
newPoint(100,180,el1);


newPoint(50,50,el2);
newPoint(90, 155,el2);
newPoint(0, 165, el2);

newPoint(50,50,el3);
newPoint(0, 165, el3);
newPoint(0,20, el3);
draw();

function newPoint(x, y, path) {
    path.points.push({
        x: x,
        y: y
    });
}


function draw() {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    for (p = 0; p < paths.length; p++) {

        var path = paths[p];

        ctx.beginPath();

        ctx.moveTo(path.points[0].x, path.points[0].y);

        for (pt = 1; pt < path.points.length; pt++) {
            var point = path.points[pt];
            ctx.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
        }

        //
        ctx.fillStyle = path.fill;
        ctx.lineWidth = path.lineWidth;
        ctx.fill();

    }

}
$('#redraw').click(function(){
  paths[0].points[2].y = 300;
  paths[1].points[1].y = 300;
  draw();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kaggqf94/4/

I am not sure if this is the best way to implement this animation (instead of those triangles will be some elements with text and images), I can't figure out how should I make the animation more slower, I guess I will have to change all code for this.

Any advice will help, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `draw()` function that will let you draw your "cropped wedges" with the green, red & blue portions each animating from equal angles to a large angle.

You can slow the animation by decreasing `pctIncrement` and quicken the animation by increasing `pctIncrement`.

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

ctx.textAlign='center';
ctx.textBaseline='middle';
ctx.font='24px arial';

var cx=cw/2;
var cy=ch/2;
var radius=250;
var startAngle=-Math.PI/8;
var totAngle=Math.PI*5/4;
var currentPct=1/3;
var currentColor='Blue';
var pctIncrement=Math.PI*2/6000;

requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function animate(time){
    draw(currentPct,currentColor);
    currentPct+=pctIncrement;
    if(currentPct>0.50){
        currentPct=1/3;
        currentColor=(currentColor=='Blue')?'Red':(currentColor=='Red')?'Green':'Blue';
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function draw(pct,color){
    var maxAngle=totAngle*pct;
    var minAngle=(totAngle-maxAngle)/2;
    var bsa,bea,rsa,rea,gsa,gea;
    if(color=='Blue'){
        bsa=startAngle;
        bea=rsa=bsa+maxAngle;
        rea=gsa=rsa+minAngle;
        gea=gsa+minAngle;
    }else if(color=='Red'){
        bsa=startAngle;
        bea=rsa=startAngle+minAngle;
        rea=gsa=rsa+maxAngle;
        gea=gsa+minAngle;
    }else{
        bsa=startAngle;
        bea=rsa=startAngle+minAngle;
        rea=gsa=rsa+minAngle;
        gea=gsa+maxAngle;
    }
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    fillArc(bsa,bea,'blue');
    fillArc(rsa,rea,'red');
    fillArc(gsa,gea,'green');
    ctx.fillStyle=color;
    ctx.fillText('Expanding',cx,cy-70);
    ctx.fillText(color,cx,cy-40);
}

function fillArc(sa,ea,fill){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(cx,cy);
    ctx.arc(cx,cy,radius,sa,ea);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle=fill;
    ctx.fill();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I can't accept your answer because I haven't 15 reputation. :( The click event should be accomplished by calculating: canvas width and element width, then animate the right element, is it right?

Comment: Your paths are actually wedges (like parts of a pie) and here is a [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29034251/how-do-i-bind-onclick-event-to-piechart-segment/29040839#29040839) showing how to track the mouse inside a wedge. BTW, you can accept an answer at any reputation level (by clicking the checkmark until it turns green). You are correct that you can't upvote until you get more reputation (by clicking the upward triangle until it turns gold). Good luck with your project!